# AngularJS routing #! issue

Tags: angularjs, routes

This question has been answered before but potentially for an earlier version of Angular.  I'm working in Angular 1.6.1.  The HTML5 isn't adding the #! to the URL but my partials aren't loading.

HTML:

```
<head>
...
<base href="localhost/test/angular/Jan102017">
...
<head>
<body>
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
.when('#/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

.when('#/second', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
})

.when('#/second/:num', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
})

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Comment: I dont't think `#` is required while defining  routes

Answer (score 0):

change all of these `when('#/'` ...  to `when('/'` ... Since you use html5Mode true

And In angular 1.6 version `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` is the default so change it like below

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: I've removed # for the three 'when' statements and now my 'home' and 'second' links take me to the root of localhost or localhost/second.  The routing didn't change and doesn't display my template content.

Comment: did you put <div ui-view></div> in your html ?

Comment: I have a <div ng-view> element.  When I add      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); I get an error: TypeError: dbg is undefined in the console.